# SSH external connections do not have my git config

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-tunnel, git-config

I have setup git nicely locally. I can push and pull without entering my passphrase. This all works great when  i open up a terminal locally.

But when I SSH in from home I seem to have lost my git config or something as when I pull i get "Enter passphrase for key" error. I can "git status" ok but not pull.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Git config is not committed into the repository.

A .gitconfig file sets up configuration options that only affect this particular repository, i.e your local. If this file were committed, the settings contained within would impact all of the users that clone the repo. This is not ideal.

Comment: I think i may have not explained this correctly. I am performing the same task each time. Just once by opening the gnome-terminal and another time connecting via SSH to the PC before performing the exact same tasks. It is the same repository

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. I have added to the .bashrc file the following

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add
```

It seems the keyring daemon was not working for ssh sessions.